# Is creating an authentication-key (mac) from the encryption password a vulnerability?

Tags: encryption, authentication, mac, gcm, pbkdf-2

I can think of at least one problem with it - that testing for a correct key (when brute forcing) is simpler with a mac key (at least for short messages) and therefore can help brute force decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create both an encryption key and authentication key from a password securely.

It is very likely that an attacker knows part of the plaintext most of the time. That makes it very possible to verify correct guesses of the password, even without verifying an authentication tag (MAC). This is especially true if there are *multiple* messages to test.

So although it is perfectly possible to verify a MAC key over purely random messages and impossible to do the same for encryption keys, the addition of a MAC should not make much of a difference for structured messages.

For passwords brute forcing can certainly be used, but slightly more advanced techniques such as dictionary attacks may also be used. Usually some form of key strengthening is used to derive master key material. That master key material can then be used to derive an encryption and MAC key.

These keys can be made cryptographically independent from each other. But that doesn't matter much since finding the password is the easiest form of attack and finding the password will of course allow an attacker to calculate both keys.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how the 2nd to last paragraph is related to the question, though. Or perhaps you were just hinting about the need for something like PBKDF's. So the bottom line seems to be - it might have _some_ effect in certain cases, but is not a major problem. Thanks again.

Comment: (I see that your profile includes that the following is not true: `thinking that OTP (XOR-encryption) can be made secure...`. I thought that was _the_ most secure encryption... Or should I post a question about it?)

Comment: No need. It's just that it is *practically* impossible; generally there are either problems with the RNG (being a PRNG, for instance) or key distribution. OTP is very useful as a theoretic construct and as the underlying idea for stream ciphers (that are non-plaintext aware) . Basically it is a slight warning for posting questions such as "is my scheme an OTP" while being build up from stream ciphers, PRNGs or TRNG's which cannot practically proven to provide random numbers. Use a stream cipher :)